# how to avoid updation of id column

Tags: sql, jdbc

I don't want to update the `id` column because it is auto incremented .
when I run this code then i face

> java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.

so my question is how to avoid / bypass the update.

```
 String sql="";
                  sql = "insert into registration(first_name,last_name,gender,email_id,dob,"
                 + "father_name,mother_name,contact,mobile,address,city,country,graduation,"
                 + "graduation_marks,graduation_year,inter,inter_marks,inter_year,high_school,"
                 + "high_marks,high_year,role,salary,resume,photo,pre_comp) value(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
                    //   int i=0;        
                        PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(sql);


                        p.setString(2,registration.first_name);
                        p.setString(3,registration.last_name);
                        p.setString(4,registration.gender);
                        p.setString(5,registration.email_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the error message: "No value specified for parameter 1"

The problem here is that "first_name" is the first column in insert query for which it will expect a value.

But your PreparedStatement sets the parameter values starting from index 2. It should be done starting with index 1

That is, p.setString(1, registration.first_name)